# Failing at inserting a new line in existing xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I am currently writing a python code to manage an existing xml file.

I have this existing xml structure in a model file :

```
<MYPROJECT>
  <VERSION>2</VERSION>
  <LANGUAGE>english</LANGUAGE>
  <FILE>
    <FILENAME>Z</FILENAME>
  </FILE>
  <PANEL1>
    <SOURCE>
      <LAYER>MISSING</LAYER>
      <NAME>MISSING</NAME>
      <ID>MISSING</ID>
    </SOURCE>
  </PANEL1>
</MYPROJECT>
```

I need to be able to insert a new tag with its value in "Source" subelement. I want to get this in the end :

```
<MYPROJECT>
  <VERSION>2</VERSION>
  <LANGUAGE>english</LANGUAGE>
  <FILE>
    <FILENAME>toto</FILENAME>
  </FILE>
  <PANEL1>
    <SOURCE>
      <LAYER>A</LAYER>
      <NAME>B</NAME>
      <ID>C</ID>
      <NEW_TAG>XX</NEW_TAG>
    </SOURCE>
  </PANEL1>
</MYPROJECT>
```

To get this, I use *xml.etree.ElementTree* and the *insert* function. Here is my code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

cheminXML = r"mypath"

def majXML (cheminXML):
        tree = ET.parse(cheminXML)

        tagProject = ET.Element("MYPROJECT")
        tagPanel1 = ET.SubElement(tagProject,'PANEL1')
        tagSource = ET.SubElement(tagPanel1,'SOURCE')
        tagNewTag = ET.SubElement(tagSource, 'NEW_TAG')
        tagNewTag.text = "apple"
        print(tagNewTag.text)
        tagSource.insert(0,tagNewTag)

        tagFilename = tree.find(".//FILENAME")
        tagFilename.text = "toto"

        tree.write(cheminXML)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        majXML(cheminXML)
```

The new tag value is printed as it should.
When I open my xml file, the filename value is "toto".

However, the new tag and its value are not written in the file.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following bit of your code is completely independent of the `tree` you loaded:

```py
        tagProject = ET.Element("MYPROJECT")
        tagPanel1 = ET.SubElement(tagProject,'PANEL1')
        tagSource = ET.SubElement(tagPanel1,'SOURCE')
        tagNewTag = ET.SubElement(tagSource, 'NEW_TAG')
        tagNewTag.text = "apple"
        print(tagNewTag.text)
        tagSource.insert(0,tagNewTag)
```

Basically, you just create a new `ET.Element` from scratch, which you could write to a file with `ET.ElementTree(tagProject).write('tagproject.xml')`.

On the other hand, you get `tagFilename` from the actual `tree` that you loaded, which means that you modify `tree`.

The solution is to make the other edits also by taking the nodes from `tree` rather than making new ones from scratch:

```py
        tagSource = tree.find('.//SOURCE')   # tagSource is tree node, not a new one
        tagNewTag = ET.SubElement(tagSource, 'NEW_TAG')
        tagNewTag.text = "apple"
```

Comment: I understand. I tried calling my tag directly from tree as you said, and it works very well, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can append the tag list, like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("unknown.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

# redefine content
root.find(".//FILENAME").text = 'todo'
root.find(".//LAYER").text = 'A'
root.find(".//NAME").text = 'B'
root.find(".//ID").text = 'C'

# define and add a new element
new=ET.Element('NEW_TAG')
new.text = 'XX'
   
for elem in root.find('.//PANEL1'):
    elem.append(new)

ET.dump(root)
tree.write("New_unknown.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Output file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<MYPROJECT>
  <VERSION>2</VERSION>
  <LANGUAGE>english</LANGUAGE>
  <FILE>
    <FILENAME>todo</FILENAME>
  </FILE>
  <PANEL1>
    <SOURCE>
      <LAYER>A</LAYER>
      <NAME>B</NAME>
      <ID>C</ID>
      <NEW_TAG>XX</NEW_TAG>
    </SOURCE>
  </PANEL1>
</MYPROJECT>
```